# Unable to upload a shared pom to Nexus

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus, m2e

I have a shared pom which uses the spring api.

pom.xml :

```
   <project>

        <groupId>com.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>profile</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <distributionManagement>
                <snapshotRepository>
                    <id>nexus-snapshot</id>
                    <url>https://mynexusrepo</url>
                </snapshotRepository>
            </distributionManagement>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
              <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
              <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>   
        </dependencies>
    </project>
```

When I try to upload the pom file to the snapshot nexus repository I receive the error :
`ReasonPhrase:Forbidden. -`

I have uploaded other pom files but they were jar's -  `<packaging>jar</packaging>`
where here I am uploading  a pom - `<packaging>pom</packaging>`

How can I upload a shared pom to Nexus so that other projects can reference it? Is this standard practice ?
Pom file is shortened, most of dependencies have been removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this shared pom belong to a project which can be deployed via mvn deploy ? Does it have correct configurations for scm ?. The usual way to do such a thing is via mvn release:prepare and release:perform. How did you tried it?

Comment: "Does this shared pom belong to a project which can be deployed via mvn deploy ? The maven project just contains a pom file and nothing else. So I should be able to just mvn deploy ?" I can install the shared pom using "mvn install". I did not use "mvn release:prepare" when adding other projects to Nexus. I tried "mvn deploy" to upload the project to Nexus but "ReasonPhrase:Forbidden." error is returned.

Comment: Sound you missed the authentication information in your settings.xml file.

Comment: mvn release:prepare release:perform is the correct way to release a pom in this case as well as maven projects

Comment: But I am not commiting any changes to SCM using maven. Currently I just need to add the .pom & its project to Nexus.

Comment: Have you checked the permissions in the settings.xml ? Furthermore i suggested to use the maven release process to release modules/pom's etc. as usual maven artifacts which is the simplest process.

Answer (score 3):

The "forbidden" message would indicate to me that your nexus userid does not have the correct permissions to publish the artifact.

If your Nexus administrator has you publishing content to a shared repository the issue could be with the repository target. Targets control the URL path which you're allowed to access.

The following blog article describes different approaches to managing the Nexus repo:

http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/06/optimal-nexus-repository-configuration/